# No response on click when .js script is imported

Tags: javascript, html

[This code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/NATrU/):

HTML

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="doctor" /> Doctor
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="police" checked /> Policia
</form>
```

JS

```
var category = null;
$("input[name='category']").click(function() {
    category = this.value;
    alert(category);
});
```

When you click a radio button immediate response is received.
But, when you have the same script in external javascript file. Its not working. 
Above code works when both are there in one html file.

If I do the same thing in different files say, index.html and jscript.js

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="doctor" /> Doctor
  <input type="radio" name="category" value="police" checked /> Policia
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

jscript.js

```
var category = null;
$("input[name='category']").click(function() {
    category = this.value;
    alert(category);
});
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the code. How you are using it in external Java?

Comment: could you share your html and external javascript file?

Comment: where is your js import code?

Comment: Make sure you've added jQuery script tag before your own script file tag.

Comment: Is your script wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` function or `$(window).load()` function?  Also, in your category variable, try changing `this.value` to `$(this).val()`.  I'm not certain that will fix it, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add deffer attribute to your script import. It will execute js AFTER your html is rendered-supported by all browsers.
REF:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Or if you are using jQuery make sure that all handlers are added in a onready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var category = null;
$("input[name=category]").click(function() { // you don;t need quotes here for category name
    category = this.value;
    alert(category);
});
});
```

Comment: Its working, waiting to mark the answer correct.
I need to use this category to auto suggest some words based on the category in a textbox. Autosuggest doesn't work.
If remove the code above and just put a category name its working. But, I'm unable to use the category received to auto suggest. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Glad I could help:) Good luck with project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the jquery .load function in your external file:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var category = null;
    $("input[name='category']").click(function() {
        category = this.value;
        alert(category);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import Your js file in under your html code and before closing body tag . Then Run

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Your code here....

});
```